# Website showing special characters like diamond with question mark

Tags: database, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, collation

I have a website which is running on asp.net 2.0. It is using sql server 2005 earlier. It was running perfectly earlier. Recently I converted this website to .net 4.0 using visual studio 2010. It is working fine at my local environment.

When I hosted this with hosting provider then it is showing many characters including Diamonds with question mark. I understand it is charset problem and I have tried following things

1. removed all database call then webpage shows correctly
2. changed tag in head `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to ISO-8859-1 but of no benefit
3. made all varchar columns in database to nvarchar but of no use

Comment: my hosting space used MSSQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of "changed tag in head to ISO-8859-1 but of no benefit" try this:"UTF-8"

Comment: Sorry, i already did this. i changed UTF-8 to latin as you specified.